# How can I get the size of an s3 bucket using Jets3t

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jets3t

I am trying to calculate the total size of an S3 bucket using my `Java Spring MVC` web application. I am using `jets3t`for my S3 access.

I have the following method to calculate the total file size of an S3 bucket.

```
public Long getBucketSize(String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey, String bucketname) throws IOException, S3ServiceException 
{
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = 
            new AWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
    S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials);
    S3Object[] objects = s3Service.listObjects(bucketname);
    if(objects != null) 
    {
        for (S3Object s3Object : objects) 
        {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I cannot find any way to calculate the total file size of a bucket. Is there any way to find that?

Comment: hmm, there is no easy way to get the size, you can just iterate through files and get the size from metadata (Content-Length property)

Comment: @nafas, Content-Length is a long value, is there any way to get the size in MB

Comment: mate, content-length, is the number of bytes, to get the size in MB you can  divide the value by 2^20 (ofcourse you should consider the floating values too)